# Import two or multiple class models to a single controller on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, database, import, controller

I'm very new to [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET), but I know a little programming in Java. I want to use a [ZIP code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_code) to query a database which will return a string, then use that string to query another database. I wanted to do this on the same control model. I thought it would be easy, and it sounds pretty easy.

When I created the controller, I put the model class of the first database, and, so far, I've gotten as far as querying the first database, but now that I have the string I want to query a second database through the DBEntities.

This displays an error saying:

```
> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FinalBallot.Models.AgainCandidate]',
> but this dictionary requires a model item of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[FinalBallot.Models.ZipTable]'.
```

Is there a way to solve this in an easy way?

```
public class Default1Controller : Controller
{
    private CandidatesDBEntities db = new CandidatesDBEntities();

    public string districString = "";
    //
    // GET: /Default1/

    public ViewResult Index(string searchString)
    {
        var queryZip = from s in db.ZipTables select s;
        var queryCandidates = from s1 in db.AgainCandidates select s1;
        double sT = 0;

        //method so it doesnt display the whole db
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            queryZip = queryZip.Where(s => s.ZipL.Equals(0));
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            sT = double.Parse(searchString);
            queryZip = queryZip.Where(s => s.ZipL.Equals(sT));

            try
            {
                districString = queryZip.ToList().ElementAt(0).District;
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(districString))
            {
                queryCandidates = queryCandidates.Where(s1 => s1.District.Equals(districString));
            }
        }
        return View(queryCandidates.ToList());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view, did you specify the model to be `IEnumerable<ZipTable>`?  The model that you're passing to your view is `IEnumerable<AgainCandidate>`, so you would get an error if you specified your model as something else.  You'd need to change the model in your view to be `IEnumerable<AgainCandidate>`.

UPDATE:
Based on your revised explanation, you can do a couple things: 
1) create a "ViewModel" that has two properties for each of your collections you want to display on the page like so:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    IEnumerable<ZipTable> Zips { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<AgainCandidate> Candidates { get; set; }
}
```

Instantiate that in your action method and return that as your model.  This would be my preferred approach.

2) Stash your two collections in the ViewData bag in your action method:

```
ViewData["Zips"] = queryZip.ToList();
ViewData["Candidates"] = queryCandidates.ToList();

return View(ViewData);
```

You can pull this data in your view like this:

```
@foreach (var zip in ViewData["Zips"] as IEnumerable<ZipTable>) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Its specified to be ZipTable, because the first query is with IEnumerable<ZipTable>  but i want to make a second query and display the view of a second table the "IEnumerable<AgainCadidate>"  I think if I changed to AgainCandidate, it will display an error because it wouldnt recognize the ZipTable.

Comment: Updated post based on your feedback.

Comment: Thank you for the answer i will try to implement that, because I'm not too familiar, so im starting reading about the ViewModel and how to implement the first solution, thank you